# If date string is + or - 5 minutes then

Tags: linux, bash, date, if-statement

I am new to bash scripts and trying to work an if statement out.

I want to do a check to see if the date stamp of a file is + or - 5 minutes from the time now. I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
MODDATE=$(stat -c '%y' test.txt)
echo moddate= $MODDATE
MODDATE=$(echo $MODDATE |head --bytes=+16)
echo now = $MODDATE

currentdate2=$(date -d "+5 minutes" '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
currentdate3=$(date -d "-5 minutes" '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

echo currentdate2 = $currentdate2
echo currentdate3 = $currentdate3
```

So this gives me the datestamp of the file (MODDATE) and the date now + or - 5 minutes.

How can i do an IF statement to say "if $MODDATE is between $currentdate2 (+5 minutes from now) and $currentdate3 (-5 minutes from now)" then echo [1] > output.txt ELSE echo [0] > output.txt .

Thank you for all of your help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about you don't try to parse the output of `stat` and directly take its output in seconds since Epoch with `%Y`? It would then be easier to use Bash's arithmetic.

Your script would look like this (with proper quoting, modern Bash constructs and lowercase variable names):

```
#!/bin/bash

moddate=$(stat -c '%Y' test.txt)
echo "moddate=$moddate"

now=$(date +%s)

if ((moddate<=now+5*60)) && ((moddate>=now-5*60)); then
    echo "[1]" > output.txt
else
    echo "[0]" > output.txt
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to use `date %s` to have the date in seconds since 1/1/1970 and make date comparison much easier.

```
currentdate2=$(date -d "+5 minutes" '+%s')
currentdate3=$(date -d "-5 minutes" '+%s')
```

Hence,

```
if [ $moddate -ge $currentdate2 ] && [ $moddate -le $currentdate3 ]; then
  ....
fi
```

should make it.

Or even shorter:

```
[ $moddate -ge $currentdate2 ] && [ $moddate -le $currentdate3 ] && echo "in interval!"
```

Comment: Thank you for this I managed to get it working like this but have since found the code from gniourf_gniourf to be a lot neater